# Dygraphs: fill area above series

Tags: r, dygraphs

There is an option in Dygraphs to fill the aera under the lines:

```
library(dygraphs)
lungDeaths <- cbind(ldeaths, mdeaths, fdeaths)
dygraph(lungDeaths, main = "Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)") %>%
  dySeries("fdeaths", stepPlot = TRUE, color = "red", fillGraph = TRUE)
```

My question is: how to fill the area *above* the lines?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is an obvious way to color above the lines. I'm curious, why would want to know this?

Comment: I'm trying to create something like [this](http://ritholtz.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/20120913.ES_.Z12.2.png)

Comment: I've posted my best solution so far below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the closest I can get, at this time. You've got to create the **illusion** of a shaded graph. You have to create a **top** dummy dataset to accomplish this to plot what you're asking about. After this, you can set the axis limits to get what you asked about.

**Note:** The bottom portion is rather tricky to include given we are **stacking** them onto top of each other. It's not ideal (what's posted below).

```
library(dygraphs)

top <- structure(rep(10000, 72), .Tsp = c(1974, 1979.91666666667, 12), class = "ts")


lungDeaths <- cbind(top, ldeaths, mdeaths, fdeaths)


dygraph(lungDeaths, main = "Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)") %>%
  dyLegend(show = "never", hideOnMouseOut = FALSE)%>%
  dyOptions(stackedGraph = TRUE)%>%
  dyRangeSelector()%>%
  dyAxis("y", valueRange = c(0, 8000))
```

[image]

If you want a large gap below, then try adding some other dummy values, like this.

```
lungDeaths <- cbind(top, ldeaths, mdeaths, fdeaths, top)

dygraph(lungDeaths, main = "Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)") %>%
  dyLegend(show = "never", hideOnMouseOut = FALSE)%>%
  dyOptions(stackedGraph = TRUE)%>%
  dyRangeSelector()%>%
  dyAxis("y", valueRange = c(8000, 20000))
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very, very good. Please let me a bit of time to review this before accepting: I had a long day already.

Comment: Glad to help. This is a nice challenge to think about.